# GitBlit Cant find Repositories after Jboss Restart

Tags: git, jboss, gitblit

I have GitBlit V1.2.1 Running on Jboss V7.1.1.Final 
Each time i restart Jboss, GitBlit (Cant Read/looses) the repositories i had.

After Searching for the repos i found one in:

```
C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp80c1b03732519896\gitblit.war-c0e0d54fb24b902\WEB-INF\data\git\test.git
```

What should be done to make sure that GitBlit dose not loose the repositories after Jboss restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Gitblit WAR stores it's data within the webapp folder.  The [Gitblit WAR setup instructions](http://gitblit.com/setup_war.html) recommend that you should manually specify a new **baseFolder** value in the web.xml file.